# Комментарии по поводу исследования

Tags: php, orm, mvc

1) папку типа protected я бы расположил не на уровне паблик-файлов index.php и .htaccess, а на уровень выше document_root. тогда это будет реальный protected без всяких .htaccess в ней и т.п

2) нужно использовать пространства имён, и соотвественно можно делать автолоадинг на них

3) не понимаю этой помешанности на синглтонах, паттерн очень сомнительный, не уверен что аппликая это обязательно один экземпляр. а если и один, то вряд ли здесь есть какая-то практическая польза от использования этого паттерна

4) по active record ничего не скажу, не люблю этот паттерн

5) чем полезны в контроллере **call и** callStatic? может быть просто сделать обработку всех возможных типов ошибок и исключений в ядре, включая syntax errors и т.п?

6) ну и html из контроллера и так понятно, что плохое решение. и это куда важнее, чем тот же active record. т.к нету пока что MVC, а только MC.
все пункты достаточно субъективны, надеюсь никого не обидел

Comment: @psychomc, я не знаю, какое именно исследование вы комментируете, но

1. Да, это была очень большая блевня со стороны Yii в свое время, сейчас все делают отдельную папку web/public под внешний доступ и ассеты.

2. Да, просто, скажем, года два назад не было распространенных PSR и никто ни о чем не думал

Comment: вот это "исследование"
http://hashcode.ru/research/325549/mvc-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83-php-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-active-record

может быть я не совсем понял как правильно нужно добавлять ответы

Comment: @psychomc, я просто в правую колонку не заглянул, все норм. Подробней чуть позже распишу, думаю.